# ForEach updates view unnecessarily

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is my code:

```swift
struct TestPageView: View {
    @State var blocks: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(blocks, id: \.self) { block in
                TestView(block, $blocks)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var blocks: [String]
    let block: String
    
    init(_ block: String, _ blocks: Binding<[String]>){
        print("Created empty view")
        self.block = block
        self._blocks = blocks
    }
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Test view", text: .constant(block), onCommit: {
            print("Committed")
            blocks.append("new element")
        })
    }
}
```

Basic idea is that my ForEach loops over my blocks, showing them. When a user performs an action while a block is focused (`onCommit` here), I need a new block to be added to the list. This code actually does that correctly; the problem is with performance. With the above print statements, the following is the output:

```
Created empty view
Created empty view
Created empty view
Committed
Created empty view
Created empty view
Created empty view
Created empty view
```

so it seems the ForEach re-renders all of the items in the list. In this simple example, it's not an issue, but in my real problem, recreating all the `TestView`s is a large task, and completely unnecessary: I just need the new element to be added, everything else can be left the same. Is there a good way to do this?

**Note**: The `\.self` is not the issue. I've tried this with making the "blocks" conform to `Identifiable`. The ForEach still fails to recognize the same ids and still creates the views again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of black-box behavior that happens with SwiftUI, without enough documentation unfortunately.

At a high level, SwiftUI tries to see which view's bodies need to be invalidated and recomputed. Body re-rendering is a fairly expensive operation, so SwiftUI tries to only do this when needed.

That being said, `init` **should be very inexpensive!** Views get initialized all the time as SwiftUI builds and diffs the view tree.

What you should be looking at is the number of times a body is computed, not the number of times an `init` is called.

And it so happens, that `TestView`'s body ***is*** getting recomputed every time. Why? The reason for that is almost certainly due to `@Binding var blocks`.

When any `@State` or `@Binding` or `@ObservedObject` is changed, SwiftUI recomputes the body. So, having `@Binding var blocks`, tells SwiftUI that `TestView` depends on that state, and when `blocks` array gets updated, it invalidates all the `TestView`s within ForEach.

What you can do instead is pass an `onCommit` closure to `TestView` and add a new element to `blocks` by the parent `TestPageView`, which is also the owner of `blocks`:

```
struct TestView: View {
   var block: String
   var onCommit: ((String) -> Void)? = nil
    
   var body: some View {
      TextField("Test view", text: .constant(self.block), onCommit: {
         self.onCommit?(self.block)
      })
   }
}
```

```
// in TestPageView
ForEach(blocks, id: \.self) { block in
   TestView(block: block) { txt in
      self.blocks.append(txt)
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, this (surprisingly to me) also doesn't solve the situation, since for some reason SwiftUI determines that having a closure property means that the view should be recomputed.

Fortunately, there's a way to finally convince SwiftUI that we know that the view actually doesn't need to be recomputed with conformance to `Equatable`, where we could tell SwiftUI exactly how to compare view changes.

```
extension TestView: Equatable {
   static func == (lhs: TestView, rhs: TestView) -> Bool {
      lhs.block == rhs.block
   }
}
```

And use an `.equatable` modifier when you use the view:

```
TestView(block: block) { txt in
   self.blocks.append(txt)
}.equatable()
```

---

FYI, using `.constant(value)` binding doesn't make much sense, except for preview. I left it here, since you used it in your example.

Comment: Unfortunately, your second solution did not work for me. The views still get recomputed. It's not so much that the views are expensive; it's that they perform a specific action when they get created, and I would really like this action to fire only once for each new  block that is added.

Comment: Actually I put in the print statements again, and I realized that maybe the print statements were altering the execution. I used breakpoints when the view gets initialized, and adding a new element only gets 3 elements to get recomputed, not 4. Which is a bit confusing; I imagine the one I committed on is the one not being recomputed but why are the other two?

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say "recomputed", are you talking about `init` or about `body`? This doesn't solve for `init` - I think `init` is always called when the parent's body is recomputed

Comment: Are you sure? I thought ForEach was not supposed to do that; when a new element is added to the list it's iterating over, it doesn't reinitialize the child views that haven't changed? Although I just tried it and it seems it does not do that...I'm pretty lost 

Comment: @user4500882, I could be wrong about the implementation of `ForEach`, but what I tried to do was to create a simple `PrinterView` that doesn't have any state, and just prints "init" in `init` and "body" in `body` (plus returning a `Text("")`), an use a ForEach over it. And it always `init`s the views, but only computes the body of a newly added `PrinterView`.

Comment: I don't understand that. How can the `init` be called without the body being recomputed? Views are struct types, so I thought if `init` is called, a new instance is being made, i.e. the body will also be made again.

Comment: @user4500882 - No. Why would that happen? `body` is a computed property. It's only evaluated when something invokes `someView.body`, which happens when SwiftUI determines that a view's body should be re-rendered. Here's a blog that might help: https://blog.scottlogic.com/2020/01/28/Exploring-SwiftUI-3-View-Updates.html

Comment: Ohh...shoot. I see what you're saying. All of the child views get reinitialized, but SwiftUI determines their body hasn't updated, so it doesn't call that property. This seems counterintuitive...right? If a view hasn't updated, why bother reinitializing it and not call the body rather than just not reinitializing it?

Comment: I'm guessing, because it *could* change depending on the init params, but also because it's needed to (re)create the view tree. So, views should be lightning fast to init.

Comment: I think since you have actually answered my question correctly, I'll mark it correct. But once I have a better understanding of this idea, I'll maybe update the question to better explain what I was looking for and what might've solved it.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new question instead of updating the old one